# How to find which list an email address is tied to?

Tags: 2013, email-enabled-library

I have an email address I want to use to email enable a discussion.  SharePoint says the email address is already in use.  How do I find what list/document library this email is tied to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled together some javascript using SPServices and JQuery that runs through all sites and subsites in a site collection, listing everything that has an external email. Once you get a list object you're looking for something in property "EmailAlias" - that's the address.

```
function getAllEmails(url) {
        siteList = "<table><tr style='background-color: #78FF78'><td class='fmgTD'><b>Site</b></td><td class='fmgTD'><b>List</b></td><td class='fmgTD'><b>Email Address</b></td></tr>";
    getSiteLists(url, "Home");
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetWebCollection",
        webURL: url,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            //      alert(xData.responseText);
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function() {

                getSiteLists($(this).attr("Url"),$(this).attr("Title"));

                url = $(this).attr("Url");
                getSubSites(url);

            });
        }
    });
    siteList += "</table>";
    $('#fmgSites').append(siteList);

}
function getSiteLists(weburl ,webtitle) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListCollection",
        webURL: weburl,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            var count = 0;
            $(xData.responseXML).find("List").each(function() {
                if($(this).attr("EmailAlias") && $(this).attr("EmailAlias").substr(0,13) != 'recordscenter'){
                    if(count == 0) {
                    siteList += "<tr><td class='fmgTD'>" + webtitle + "</td>";
                    } else {
                    siteList += "<tr><td class='fmgTD'>&nbsp;</td>";
                    }
                    count++;
                    siteList += "<td class='fmgTD'>" + $(this).attr("Title") + "</td><td class='fmgTD'><b>" +$(this).attr("EmailAlias") + "</b>@YOURSITEEMAILADDRESS</td></tr>";
                }
            }); 
        }               

    });
}
function getSubSites(weburl) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetWebCollection",
        webURL: weburl,
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, status) {
            //      alert(xData.responseText);
            $(xData.responseXML).find("Web").each(function() {
                // now get all ists for this web
                getSiteLists($(this).attr("Url"),$(this).attr("Title") );
                getSubSites($(this).attr("Url"));

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to solve the problem.  I was looking for a way to do this without custom code,  This looks like the best way to get the values.  Thanks!